# sum of data in array and add the same sum in same array at bottom

Tags: laravel

I am self leaner and stuck at getting the sum of array which i am getting.
Ref. attached image showing the array.
for Month of Aug.

```
   "Aug-2022" => array:6 [▼

  "annualbuffalomilksalerecordforcustomer" => "8.00"
  "annuala2milksalerecordforcustomer" => "5.50"
  "annualjerseymilksalerecordforcustomer" => "2.50"
  "annualbuffalomilksalerecord" => "168.00"
  "annuala2milksalerecord" => "0.00"
  "annualjerseymilksalerecord" => "390.00"

Here i want the sum all 6 which is = 574.00

expected result is -

   "Aug-2022" => array:6 [▼

  "annualbuffalomilksalerecordforcustomer" => "8.00"
  "annuala2milksalerecordforcustomer" => "5.50"
  "annualjerseymilksalerecordforcustomer" => "2.50"
  "annualbuffalomilksalerecord" => "168.00"
  "annuala2milksalerecord" => "0.00"
  "annualjerseymilksalerecord" => "390.00"
  "sumofmilksale" => "574.00"
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this using the [`map()`](https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-map) function :

```php
$collection = collect([
  'Apr-2022' => [
    "annualbuffalomilksalerecordforcustomer" => "8.00",
    "annuala2milksalerecordforcustomer" => "5.50",
    "annualjerseymilksalerecordforcustomer" => "2.50",
    "annualbuffalomilksalerecord" => "168.00",
    "annuala2milksalerecord" => "0.00",
    "annualjerseymilksalerecord" => "390.00",
  ],
  'May-2022' => [
    "annualbuffalomilksalerecordforcustomer" => "8.00",
    "annuala2milksalerecordforcustomer" => "5.50",
    "annualjerseymilksalerecordforcustomer" => "2.50",
    "annualbuffalomilksalerecord" => "168.00",
    "annuala2milksalerecord" => "0.00",
    "annualjerseymilksalerecord" => "390.00",
  ],
]);

$mapped = $collection->map(function ($entry) {
  $sum = array_sum($entry);

  return array_merge($entry, ['sumofmilksale' => $sum]);
})

dd($mapped);
```